# Can the recipient of a block reward spend the funds in the same block?

Tags: transactions, blocks

From my understanding, when a new block is mined, the coinbase address's balance is incremented by the block reward amount. If this address had a zero balance before the block was mined and the block contains a transaction that spends funds from this address, would the block be considered valid?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, the reward is credited after all the transactions in the block are processed.

From the Yellow Paper section 11. Block Finalization

> The process of finalising a block involves four stages:
>
> 1. Validate (or, if mining, determine) ommers;
> 2. validate (or, if mining, determine) transactions;
> 3. apply rewards;
> 4. verify (or, if mining, compute a valid) state and block nonce.